# How do I configure which storage account my Web Apps and Function Apps use?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Is this even possible?  I have a couple web apps and a couple of Azure Functions running under the same App Service Plan. I'd like to (ideally) have them use a specific Storage plan, so I can keep everything in one place. I envision them in different containers under the same plan.

If that's not possible...then where are the files?  Are they on the storage that's built into the App Service Plan itself?  If so, can I connect to this somehow, so I can manage the files through something like Storage Explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to (ideally) have them use a specific Storage plan, so I can keep everything in one place. I envision them in different containers under the same plan. If that's not possible...then where are the files?

`Every Azure Web App has a home directory stored/backed by Azure Storage`. More detail info please refer to [Azure WebApp sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). It is owned by Azure WebApp Service, we are not able to choose Azure Storage to setup WebApp by ourselves currently. But we could config storage account for [Azure WebApp Diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs#manage-diagnostic-settings-in-the-portal).

> Are they on the storage that's built into the App Service Plan itself? If so, can I connect to this somehow, so I can manage the files through something like Storage Explorer?

Different [WebApp Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#scale-an-app-service-plan) has different volume of the storage. We could use Kudu tool (https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net) to manage the files.  More detail info about Kudu please refer to the [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu).

**Update:**
We could access the home directory with the Kudu tool. More details please refer to the snapshoot
[image]

Comment: Can I access this home directory with Azure Storage Explorer? I did this one -- I was able to look in on an Azure Function app, and saw the `run.csx` and `wwwroot` files and folders, etc. If these files aren't in an Azure storage account, how could I have done this?

Comment: We can't acess this home directory with Azure Storage Explorer.  The files are in the Azure Storage account that is handled by Azure WebApp Service backend. We don't  know the account name of the storage. We could access the home directory with Kudu  tool (https://yourwebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net) I mentioned above.

Comment: I also update  the snapshoot of kudu tool in the answer.

Comment: This can't be true for Azure Functions apps. I absolutely _know_ I did this through Storage Explorer, and I still have the entire directory structure which I downloaded to my desktop as proof. I've since deleted that Functions app, so I can't replicate, but I literally downloaded the entire `site` folder structure through Storage Explorer, so it was somehow using a storage account that I could access.

Comment: We also could download the structure through the kudu tool. We also can use App Service Editer(Preview) to edit and download the whole structure in the Azure portal. You mentioned "Azure storage explore" ,does it means the [tool](http://storageexplorer.com/)?

Comment: Yes. I swear I was able to access the "backend" files of an Azure Function app through that tool. I uploaded and downloaded `.csx` files through it.

Comment: If your Azure Functions on Consumption plan, where the user storage account is used, then you could see the Azure Files in storage explorer

Answer (score 1):

Today when playing with the Azure Az Powershell tool I found I was able to provision a Function App without a Azure Storage back-end.  This cannot be done via the UI.  An easy way to provision a Function App with a storage account backend is by leveraging the Azure UI for provisioning.

When a Function App is provisioned via command line, the bits seem to be stored within the function app itself.  There is an FTP URL given if you download the publish profile.  The files can be read and written to using an FTP tool like WinSCP (as alternative to Kudu)